# How to submit iron-form and trigger form's action?

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, html-input, paper-elements

I have this form that is supposed to post the input values to the formspree API using the form's `action` attribute on submit. After I added `is="iron-form"`, it just posts the values out but doesn't trigger the `action` attribute for some reason.

```
<form is="iron-form" action="https://formspree.io/MY_EMAIL_HERE" method="post">

  <paper-input type="email" name="email" label="Your email" required></paper-input>    
  <paper-textarea name="message" label="Your message" required char-counter maxlength="2000"></paper-textarea>

  <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="{{baseUrl}}contact_form_sent" />

  <paper-button class="sendButton" on-click="_submit">Send</paper-button>
</form>

...

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-contact',
    _submit: function() {
      this.$.form.submit();
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

`this.$` is a map of IDs to nodes in the current Polymer element (see Polymer's [automatic node finding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#node-finding)). So, `this.$.form` is trying to access the element with an ID of "form", but there are no elements with that ID, so the value would be `undefined`.

You can fix this by giving your `<form>` an ID of "form":

```
<form id="form" ...>
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    _submit: function() {
      this.$.form.submit();
    },
    _onResponse: function(e) {
      this._response = JSON.stringify(e.detail.response, null, 2);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.8.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-form/iron-form.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <form id="form"
            is="iron-form"
            action="//httpbin.org/post"
            on-iron-form-response="_onResponse"
            method="post">
        <input type="text" name="test" value="foo"/>
        <paper-button raised on-tap="_submit">Submit</paper-button>
      </form>
      <pre>[[_response]]</pre>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/qRwWJB?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0):

### SOLUTION:

According to the last example on this page https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-form?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=iron-form I have to use 2 forms, so I could redirect the page to the specified URL in the `action` attribute, so I changed it accordingly:

```
  <form is="iron-form" id="redirectDemo">
      <paper-input type="email" name="email" label="Your email" required></paper-input>
      <paper-textarea name="message" label="Your message" required char-counter maxlength="2000"></paper-textarea>

      <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="{{baseUrl}}contact_form_sent" />
      <input type="text" name="_gotcha" style="display:none" />

      <paper-button class="sendButton"  on-click="_nativeSubmit">Send</paper-button>
  </form>

  <form method="post" action="URL HERE" id="nativeForm"></form>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-contact',

      _nativeSubmit: function() {
         redirectDemo = this.$.redirectDemo;
         nativeForm = this.$.nativeForm;
          if (redirectDemo.validate()) {
            // For each element the iron-form wants to submit, create a hidden
            // input in the submission form.
            var serializedItems = redirectDemo.serialize();
            for (var name in serializedItems) {
              var input = document.createElement('input');
              input.hidden = true;
              input.name = name;
              input.value = serializedItems[name];
              nativeForm.appendChild(input);
            }
            nativeForm.submit();
          }
      }

    });
  </script>
```